# Firebase overwrite default screen name

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm using the Firebase SDK and I want to give everyscreen a custom name so that I can track this.

Now when the app starts I get this info statement:

> Firebase automatic screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name

Now I don't see where I can just overwrite the default screen name, is it a property somewhere on every viewcontroller?

Comment: The method (function) that it's shows in the message is the function to call to override the default, which is the class name of the current UI view controller. Did you try calling that function?

Comment: what method is that?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to overwrite it, then I'd recommend to use the method in viewDidAppear in each of your view controller. To avoid conflicting reporting with the auto reporter as it might overwrite your own screen name, I think you might want to turn off the auto reporter:

> To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO in the Info.plist